# Google cloud logging for react JS

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-logging

Is it possible to use Google cloud logging libraries in React JS.

I have installed the winston logging library, to do cloud logging, but when I did npm start, I get almost 93 errors, where all says

```
webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
```

Can someone help in this